# Meaning and grammar of やるっきゃない

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language, particle-しか

I few minutes ago on NHK news 「注目」 I've heard/saw the phrase 「やるっきゃない」.
I have no idea what it means.. And what grammar rules are here?

Comment: 3rd result on Google explains where the phrase comes from: http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1212799662 (It's a contraction of `やるしかない`:　to have "no choice but to (just) do it". )

Comment: This word become obsolete.

Comment: But it was used today on national TV..

Comment: Because the woman who first made this word famous died today. She is 85 years old. This word became popular about 30 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[っきゃ](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%83) is an informal spoken contraction of しか, a particle.  やるっきゃない means やるしかない.

The particle しか is always followed by a negative of some sort, either an explicit negative like ない or a predicate that is semantically negative such as だめだ or あるもんか.

Taken together, しか＋ない means something like "only; nothing but".  It commonly follows nouns, but it can follow other sorts of constituents as well.  When it follows a verb, it means that the verb must be done or will unavoidably happen (= "there is no alternative to 〜").  Your example やるっきゃない means something like "have to do [it]".

Comment: Just want to add to this good answer that っきゃない is predominantly a Kantoism, meaning over 2/3 of the country would not use it much in natural settings.